# comment form doesn't send comments!

Tags: nodes, forms, comments

This is the code of my `page.tpl.php`

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="left_column"><?php include 'left_column.php'; ?></div>

    <div id="right_column_wrapper">
            <div class="section">
                <a id="main-content"></a>
               <?php print $messages; ?>
                <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
                <?php if ($title): ?><h1 class="title" id="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1><?php endif; ?>
                <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
                <?php if ($tabs): ?><div class="tabs"><?php print render($tabs); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($action_links): ?><ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul><?php endif; ?>
                <?php print render($page['content']);?>
                <?php print $feed_icons; ?>
             </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer_div">
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</div>
```

There are two content types in my website called CT1 and CT2. comment sending is open for both of them. This is template.php

```
function MyTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
    if (isset($variables['node'])) 
        {
        switch ($variables['node']->type)
        {
        case "CT1":
            $suggest = "page__node__CT";
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
        //I added the fields of CT1 here using entity_metadata_wrapper  

            $comment = new stdClass;
        $comment->nid = $variables['node']->nid;
        $variables['form'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment));  
            break;
    }
    }
}
```

and in `page--node--CT.tpl.php` I wrote this code:

```
<div id="DIV_FOR_CONTENTS">
    <?php //Contents are displayed here with some css&html format ?>
</div>
<?php
    print $form;
?>
```

it displays the form but doesn't send comments. For CT2, I created a file renamed it  to `node--CT2.tpl.php` and this is its code

```
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
  </div>

  <?php print render($content['links']); ?>

  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
<?php 
    $comment = new stdClass;
    $comment->nid = $nid;
    $form = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment));
    print $form;
?>
    </div>
```

it works and sends the comments. from what I see, they both follow the same way to display the comment form but why CT1 form doesn't work?

Comment: Any reason why you are custom printing the comment form instead of just letting it print itself as usual?
In your second node template, the line above your custom code "print render($content['comments']);" is already printing the comments and comment form.

Comment: @rooby you are right, no difference does it make. `print render($content['comments'])` doesn't provide the comment form in `page--node--CT1.tpl.php` that is why I must custom the comment form. so the only reason why I do that for CT2, is because I want to be sure that CT1 and CT2 have the same code for printing the comment form but I don't know why it doesn't work for `page--node--CT1.tpl.php` ?!

Comment: If your comments don't print normally that is a problem and instead of trying to hack around it I would probably try to work out why that is the case. I would look into comment settings, permissions etc. Also note that nodes created before you set the comment settings to open on the content type may need to be manually updated to have open comments.

Comment: @rooby finally I found it, I must suggest the theme hook in `MyTHEME_preprocess_node` not the `MyTHEME_preprocess_page`

Comment: Good you solved it, however I would still be worried more about why the comments need to be custom printed to work in the first place.

Comment: @rooby at this time it isn't needed to custom the comment form. `<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>` works for both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I must suggest the theme hook in `MyTHEME_preprocess_node` not the `MyTHEME_preprocess_page`